# Set a delay of some seconds before reloading an interstitial ad

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, ads

I want to set/add a delay when reloading an ad when it has failed to load. I think it could be done with Looper.getMainLooper() but I don´t know how to do this. You can see I have implemented that if the ad fails to load,it will be reloaded up to 5 times, so I think that adding a delay before reloading the ad could be a good option.

Here is my code:

```java
 @Override
      protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        requestNewInterstitial(5);

        }




 private void requestNewInterstitial(int maxRetry) {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        InterstitialAd.load(Activityone.this, getString(R.string.interid),
                adRequest, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {


          if (maxRetry>0){
                         
                  /*HERE IS WHERE THE AD IS RELOADED, SO THE DELAY COULD BE SET HERE BEFORE 
                 CALLING THE REQUEST NEW INTERSTITIAL FUNCTION*/
                 mInterstitialAd = null;
                 requestNewInterstitial(maxRetry-1);
              
                   
                    }
                });
                     }
           
    }




  btnPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            
                if (mInterstitialAd != null) {

                    mInterstitialAd.show(Activityone.this);

                    mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                  
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(@NonNull AdError adError) {

                        }

                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `Handler` to delay a function like this:
(Kotlin version, but you get the idea)

```kotlin
private fun reloadInterstitialAd() {
    if (maxRetry > 0) {
        val delayTime = 5000L // 5 seconds.
        val looper = mainLooper // Use `Looper.getMainLooper()` if you do not have access to an Activity context.

        mInterstitialAd = null
        Handler(looper).postDelayed({
            maxRetry--
            requestNewInterstitial(maxRetry)
        }, delayTime)
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Max reload reached")
    }
}
```

Use this function like `reloadInterstitialAd()` in the `onAdFailedToLoad` callback.

Comment: Should I also add the  `mInterstitialAd = null;` above  `requestNewInterstitial(maxRetry - 1)` as in my code  have also the line of code `mInterstitialAd = null;` or where should I put that line of code?

Comment: I have tried to make what you did in Java, but actually using new Handler in the loop is not a good practice, lets see if I can make that in Java, thanks

Comment: You can create a global `Handler` variable in your Activity & use that but I don’t think this approach would cause any issues.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do this.

```
if (maxRetry>0){
               
      //add a delay before retrying
      new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              requestNewInterstitial(maxRetry-1);

          }
      }, 1000);
  }
```

Hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: I have thought of that, but in that case, should the new Handler be outside the loop or inside of it as you did? I mean, if it is inside, wouldn´t 5 Handlers be generated if the loop reaches 5 loop turns? Wouldn't it be more correct to use only one Handler for all the loop turns and later deleting/clearing that unique handler onDestroy method so that memory leaks are avoided?

Answer (score -2):

You can use this

```
Thread.sleep(delay_time_in_milliseconds);
```

Comment: Using Handler could be better than using Thread.sleep or I can get the same result?